# Display Multiple Node in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, master-pages, nodes

I have this xml data from a web service in my application that has an output something like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<NewDataSet> 
-<Table> 


   <RecipeID>12923</RecipeID>
    <RecipeNumber>R-000023</RecipeNumber> 
    <Name>Orange Pineapple Honey chicken (2)</Name> 
    <Servings>4</Servings>
     <PrepTime>20</PrepTime> 
    <CookTime>90</CookTime>
    <MarinateTime>0</MarinateTime> 
    <StandTime>0</StandTime> 
    <ChillTime>0</ChillTime>
    <BrewTime>0</BrewTime> 
    <FreezeTime>0</FreezeTime> 
    <TotalTime>110</TotalTime>  
    <MethodHeader>Makes 4 servings</MethodHeader> 
    <SubTitle>Tasty variation of the delicious honey chicken with an orange pineapple sauce.
</Table> 
-<Table1> 


 <Description>3 lbs. skinless boneless chicken breast halves</Description>  

</Table1> 
-<Table1> 


  <Description>2 Tbsp. salt</Description> 

</Table1> 
-<Table2> 

 <Note>Preheat oven to 350°F. Thoroughly wash chicken breasts and add salt.</Note> 

</Table2> 
-<Table2> 


 <Note>Place the salted chicken breasts in a large baking dish and set them aside. To make the sauce, combine the honey and the pineapple juice.</Note> 

</table2>

</NewDataSet>
```

So I used ReadXml to put it in a dataset and display information in a DataList by using
`<%#Eval("RecipeID")%>` inside  in the source of my masterpage and so on.

The problem is when I reach to `<table1>`. I am unable to get the multiple  node(The chicken and salt). How can I fetch this two nodes. So I can proceed with the `<table2>` where in I also do the same thing and get the two `<note>` nodes

Comment: Don't have any experience in this but a wild guess you might want to try: `<%#Eval("Table1.Description")%>` or since you have multiple of the same type something like `<%#Eval("Table1[0].Description")%>`. Sorry if it doesn't work but I guess it's worth a try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used .selectNodes and get each item in loop

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create two DataTables with the same name within a single DataSet.  You can verify that by doing this:

```
var ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable("Table1"));
ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable("Table1"));
```

I think you need to collapse the two rows that are in `<Table1>` into a single table.  Then you won't have any problems binding.